# Multiply or duplicate number in a list. Python

Tags: python

How can I duplicate myData. For example

```
myLen = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

duplicate the number by the length of the 'myLen' and also convert the string to number

```
myData = ['2']
```

output:

```
[2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Comment: `res = [int(myData[0])] * len(myLen)`

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
list(map(int,myData*len(myLen)))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is selecting the index of the element you need in myLen and then apply it to my data:

```
i = 0    
n = myLen[i]
myData = ['2']**n
```

Of course you could decide what position you need by changing the value of `i` but make sure it's not greater than the length of `myLen` otherwise you'll get an error.

Basically the syntax `[x]**n` creates a list of length n with element x in it.